# What is the difference between this->data and (*this).data in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I was reading about the this pointer in my book. I encountered something ambiguous written in the book and was unable to understand it. I know that this is a special pointer which is used for determining the object which has called a certain member function of a class. Moreover as we refer to elements in a structure using the arrow operator can be related with the arrow operator used here but what is **(*this).data** for? Are they alias of each other?

Comment: Dennis Ritchie added -> so programmers wouldn't have to write that.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `this` is not a pointer, but can be used like a pointer mostly (try assignment).

Comment: @knivil Wrong, it's prvalue of pointer type. You can't assign to `const int* const` either, but you wouldn't call it "not a pointer", would you?

Comment: Can not find it as example in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category .  Maybe you can point me to a better reference. And in the example I can cast away all the constness. What about location `&this`?

Comment: @knivil a.) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this b.) That doesn't mean you can legally do this (without invoking undefined behaviour) c.) You can't do `&this` the same way you can't do `&42` (it's a prvalue)

Comment: I would argue with "prvalue expression".

Comment: @knivil, C++ standard suits you? `The keyword this names a pointer to the object for which a non-static member function (9.3.2) is invoked
or a non-static data member’s initializer (9.2) is evaluated.` - 5.1.1 / 2

Comment: You got me, from today I accept this as a full pointer. :)

Comment: @knivil, you should not argue with this. `In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value
is the address of the object for which the function is called.` 9.3.2 / 1

Comment: Maybe I will open a question, but more research on my side is needed, because `prvalue` and `prvalue expression` sounds ... different.

Comment: AFAIK `this` is a pointer and not a reference because references were added to the language at a later point by Bjarne Stroustrup, whereas classes and `this` already existed in early versions.

Comment: Guys, I thank you. Now I understand what's an 'prvalue' is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference.

```
this->data
```

is just a simplification for

`(*this).data`

It combines dereference and member access into a single operation.

Comment: The thing is there is question in my book stating, differentiate between the following expressions : (i) this ->data  (ii) (*this).data
If they are same what is the point of asking such a question ?

Comment: @Dhiraj `(*this).data` first dereferences `this` and then accesses the member `data`, `this->data` does it in one step. The difference is pure syntactical.

Comment: @DhirajBarnwal your book asks you what's the difference between `this->data` and `(*this).data` to check what you have learned. Apparently you didn't learn this basic thing from the book. I hope you understood and you will remember the explanations you got on this site.

Comment: @axiac the book I am using is full of contradictory statements. Supposedly not a very good book prescribed by my school I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

They do exactly the same in your case.

```
(*this).data 

example: this = Button* //pointer
example: *this = Button& // reference
```

A pointer and a reference to a `button` will do the same. Both will have full access to the object. The difference is the pointer needs to be accessed with the `->` operator and a reference can be accessed with the `.` operator.

Comment: @abelenky `this->` cannot be overloaded because `this` is a pointer.

Comment: Is this is a pointer or not? One of the comments in the main post says that it is not a pointer but can be used like a pointer.

Comment: *"As you know, a pointer and a reference to a button will do the same"* no one knows this but you.

Comment: @DhirajBarnwal, don't trust everything you read on the SO. `this` is a pointer - albeit of a special type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference,

```
    this->data;
    //is the same thing as 
    (*this).data;
```

The only thing we are looking at here is in terms of order of operation.  Since the . is higher up on the priority list than the *, the purist way to code it is (*this).data(to ensure the * will happen before the .).  The developpers just thought it would be a good idea to have an alternative that will defferenciate and avoid mistakes like *(this).data that could be very hard to spot and crash the program